# Some clever trick is required for this Integral with irrational power of cosine as integrand.

Tags: integration

See this:
$$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\left(#1\right)}\left\lfloor\frac{\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\sqrt{13}-1}x{\rm d}x}{\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\sqrt{13}+1}x{\rm d}x}\right\rfloor$$
Well I could only think of Cauchy-Schwarz, but it is also not fitting.

All calculations by hand, no **Beta** And that implicitly implies not using others like **Gamma** too.

Comment: How does ye olde “replace $\cos(x)$ by exponentials” tricke work in this case?

Comment: @Circonflexe can't say, maybe that's overkill sinc eI only want to find the floor.

Comment: Use the reduction formula for [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer helped, using Integration by Parts:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha+1}x{\rm d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha}x\cos x{\rm d}x=\cos^{\alpha}x\sin x\Bigg|_0^{\pi/2}+\alpha\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha-1}x\sin^2 x{\rm d}x=0+\alpha\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha-1}x{\rm d}x-\alpha\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha+1}x{\rm d}x$$
So:
$$\frac{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha-1}x{\rm d}x}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha+1}x{\rm d}x}=\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}$$

Comment: Could it be that the result is actually $\frac{\alpha + 1}{\alpha}$?

Answer (score 13):

We needn't compute the integrals.  Because $0\leq \cos x\leq1$ on $[0,\pi/2]$, the higher power of $\cos$ is less then the lower one, hence the floor is at least 1. And it is easy to estimate, that it cannot be 2 or more:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^5 x\,dx=\frac8{15},\quad
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2 x\,dx=\frac\pi4
$$

Comment: is all this intutive? I like rigorousity better.

Comment: @ADG It can be made into a fully rigorous argument quite directly.

Comment: so would you help me eliminating 2 as a possibility, cuz I can't see it now.

Comment: @ADG We can compute integrals from $\cos^n(x)$ less than and greater to $\sqrt{13}\pm1$.

Comment: @ADG Integrate by parts, $\cos^{\alpha+1} x = (\cos^\alpha x)\cdot \cos x$. Recall that $\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x$ to determine the exact quotient.

Comment: @DanielFischer (**edited**)I am getting: $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha+1}x{\rm d}x=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{\alpha-1}x{\rm d}x$$

Comment: @ADG Sign error, it's $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$. So here, you have $\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{13}+1}{\sqrt{13}}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: @DanielFischer well that's an answer in it's own, would you like to write that up?

Comment: @ADG I reserve the right to be too lazy for that. You can write it up if you want.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't force you anyways :D

Answer (score 7):

Recall that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^a(x)dx = \dfrac12 \beta(1/2,(a+1)/2) = \dfrac12 \dfrac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma((a+1)/2)}{\Gamma((a+2)/2)}$$
where $\beta(x,y)$ is the beta function and $\Gamma(z)$ is the gamma function.

Hence, the value of your expression without the floor is
$$\dfrac{\Gamma((a+1)/2)}{\Gamma((a+2)/2)} \cdot \dfrac{\Gamma((a+4)/2)}{\Gamma((a+3)/2)} = \dfrac{(a+4)/2-1}{(a+3)/2-1} = \dfrac{a+2}{a+1}=1+\dfrac1{\sqrt{13}}$$
where $a= \sqrt{13}-1$.

Comment: no beta plz, edited the post.

Comment: @ADG What do you mean?

Comment: (+1)plz don't use beta or gamma function, that's not my course level yet, sorry for not mentioning it before, but you can kee this here, that'll help other visiters, if you're looking for acceptance, maybe post another answer [sorry times3]

Comment: @ADG Done. Below is another answer, which uses nothing but basic trigonometry.

Comment: "Recall that..."

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to write
$$\cos^{a}(x) = \cos^{a+2}(x) + \sin^2(x)\cos^a(x)$$
Hence, we are after
$$1+\dfrac{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\cos^a(x)dx}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{a+2}(x)dx}$$
Clearly, $$\dfrac{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\cos^a(x)dx}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{a+2}(x)dx} > 0$$
We will now show that
$$\dfrac{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\cos^a(x)dx}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{a+2}(x)dx} < 1$$
which on rearranging gives us that, it suffices to show
$$ \text{ or }\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(2x) \cos^{a}(x)dx > 0$$
We will show that the last statement is indeed true.
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(2x) \cos^{a}(x)dx & = \int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2x) \cos^{a}(x)dx + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\cos(2x)\cos^a(x)dx\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2x) \cos^{a}(x)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(2(\pi/2-x))\cos^a(\pi/2-x)dx\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2x) \cos^{a}(x)dx + \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(\pi-2x)\sin^a(x)dx\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2x) \cos^{a}(x)dx - \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(2x)\sin^a(x)dx\\
& = \int_0^{\pi/4}\cos(2x) \left(\cos^{a}(x) - \sin^a(x) \right)dx > 0
\end{align}
where the last inequality is true, since $\cos(x) > \sin(x)$ on the interval $[0,\pi/4)$.
Hence, again we have
$$1+\dfrac{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\cos^a(x)dx}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^{a+2}(x)dx} \in (1,2)$$

Comment: @ADG "Better" is a poor choice of word. My other answer gave you the exact value and this answer rigorously gives you a bound to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Integration by parts gives, for any $\eta>0$:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{\eta+1}(x)\,dx = \frac{\eta}{\eta+1}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{\eta-1}(x)\,dx \tag{1}$$
hence by taking $\eta=\sqrt{13}$ we just need to compute:
$$\left\lfloor 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{13}}\right\rfloor = \color{red}{1}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: I have done that see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1278784/67609

Comment: @ADG: oh, sorry, I did not notice that.